# tableView methods called before viewDid load

Tags: swift, uitableview

my app load data from server and put in an array, all this performing in `viewDidLoad ()`

i use tableView to display my data from my array, method `numberOfRowsInSection()` return `MyArray.count`
put the rows does not display

and when I write in `cellForRowAtIndexPath()` this code  `let User = MyArray[indexPath.row]`
I have this error:

```
fatal error: Index out of range
(lldb)
```

are tableView methods called before `viewDidLoad()`? or What have I done wrong?

Comment: You should be loading the data from the servier asynchronously and update your table once you receive the data - long after the view is loaded.

Comment: @Mundi how i do that?

Comment: You can download project 11 and 15 from https://github.com/khuong291/Swift_Example_Series

Comment: @ khuong291 I read your code it's perfect thank you!! , but how i deal with Int data or if it is image by Alamofire and SwiftyJSON?